# Compute homography given rotation and translation between two cameras

Tags: computer-vision, transformation, homography, projective-geometry

I know that one can compute the homography matrix by using at least four correpondence points.

I was wondering if and how can I obtain a homography matrix if I already know the rotation and translation between two cameras, including the camera intrinsics?

I found something that looked like this

H= K*R*K^-1

but this assumes a pure rotation. What would be the case for a pure translation?
And what if I want to warp an image with the homography matrix that is not from points purely on a plane?

I'm somewhat confused right now and would really really appreciate any explanations! 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is a nonzero translation, and the image contains more than a plane (or you are not looking at very far away things) then the images are not related by a homography. You can convince yourself that this is the case by noticing that some points visible in one image may be occluded in the other one.

If the image shows a plane among other things, and you estimate a homography using only point correspondences on that plane, than the homography will correctly transform all points on that plane, but will map incorrectly all other points.

Comment: But you can compute a homography for pixels that correspond to a specific plane in the scene.

Comment: Ehr, that's exactly what the second paragraph in the answer says, right?

Comment: Yes, but I didn’t see an actual answer for that case.

Answer (score 2):

Given the rotation *R* and translation ***t*** and a plane with surface
normal ***n*** and a (signed) distance *d* from the origin in the scene with calibration cameras *K* and *K'* for each camera the homography induced by
the plane is

[image]

This is the subject of chapter 13 (Example 13.2) of the [canon on the subject by Hartley and Zisserman](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/hzbook/).